# Targeting images from a package

Tags: java

I recently tried to organize my files into packages and it all went smoothly except now I don't know how I can import the package containing all the images and after that I don't know how to target those images once they have been imported.

```
package game.character;

import game.tasks.ImageMake;
import game.character.MoveCha;
import game.images.SpriteSheet.png;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawCha extends JPanel {
 public MoveCha move;
 public ImageMake imgm;

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  imgm = new ImageMake();
  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

  move = new MoveCha();
  g2d.drawImage(
   imgm.createImg("SpriteSheet.png"),
   move.getX(),
   move.getY(),
   move.getX() + 40,
   move.getY() + 64,
   0,
   0,
   10,
   16,
   this
  );
 }
}
```

when I try to compile everything I get an error saying that "package game.images.SpriteSheet does not exist" I am new to using packages and do not entirely understand how they work, thanks in advance!